# How to check if SCNetwork interface configuration is hidden?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, system-configuration

I have an `SCNetworkInterfaceRef` through which i want to get all details of the interface i was able to bsd name,type mac address but unable to get `hiddenConfiguration` (hiddenConfiguration is bool value )

prefrencePlist path`/Library/Preferences/SystemConfiguration/preferences.plist`

[image]

```
SCNetworkInterfaceRef interface = SCNetworkServiceGetInterface(service);
 NSString *type  = (__bridge NSString*) SCNetworkInterfaceGetInterfaceType(interface)
 NSString *bsd  = (__bridge NSString*) SCNetworkInterfaceGetBSDName(interface);
 NSString *m = (__bridge NSString*) SCNetworkInterfaceGetHardwareAddressString(interface);
```

How to get hidden configuration value

Any suggestions would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the interface is hidden or not is not part of the public interface.

However, a private API exists, have a look at [SCNetworkConfigurationPrivate.h](https://opensource.apple.com/source/configd/configd-699.30.1/SystemConfiguration.fproj/SCNetworkConfigurationPrivate.h.auto.html), from Apples Open Source, repos.

You could just declare it an extern:

```
extern BOOL _SCNetworkInterfaceIsHiddenConfiguration(SCNetworkInterfaceRef ref);
```